# How to remove background of a low contrast image using imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am new to Imagemagick and am trying to work out a script which I can use to remove the background of a number of images.

The problems is that some images (see sample below) involve objects whose main color is very close to the background.

Can someone help me pointing the right approach and/or providing real-life examples with which I can play?

Thanks a lot!

!(http://dev.gmce.com.br/foto2-small.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
convert test.jpeg  -white-threshold 90%  -transparent white output.png
```

just play with the threshold percentage